# How to dispatch an action from a service unaware of Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

Say I have a geolocation service that is not aware of Redux and I configure it like this:

```
backgroundGeoLocation.configure(
  callback // will be called with an argument when the coordinates change
);
```

What is the cleanest way to make the service callback dispatch a Redux action without exporting `store` from a separate module and using `store.dispatch()` (because this would be a singleton)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to pass some value to some piece of code in JavaScript, you need to use functions.
For example,

```
function createGeoLocationService(store) {
  let backgroundGeoLocation = new BackgroundGeoLocation()
  backgroundGeoLocation.configure(coordinates => {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_COORDINATES', coordinates })
  })
  return backgroundGeoLocation
}
```

Now, wherever you create the store, create that service:

```
let store = createStore(reducer)
let backgroundGeoLocation = createGeoLocationService(store)
```

If you need to access it in the components, you can either:

1. Make it a singleton (yup, not what you wanted, but it’s a valid option for client-only apps)
2. Pass it down explicitly via props (can get tedious but it’s the most straightforward and explicit way)
3. Pass it down implicitly via context (very easy but you will be dealing with an [unstable API that is subject to change](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) so it’s on your conscience)

Comment: Note that `<Provider>` from `react-redux` uses the "pass it down implicitly via context" technique, so if you are using Redux you are already "dealing with an unstable API" without knowing it.

Comment: @AnsonKao You won’t need to change your app when that unstable API changes though. We hide its usage from you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to `callbackFn` be aware of `store.dispatch` then you must create something like *event stream* or *Observable* from `callbackFn`. And once you have done you simply map the stream to `store.dispatch` function.

You're free to use any lib for creating streams but i recommend [Rx](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)

In that approach you'll must come with something like:

```
var geoLocation$ = new Rx.Subject();
var newCoordinatesAction = coordinates => ({
    type: "YOUR_TUPE", 
    payload: coordinates 
});
geoLocation$.map(newCoordinatesAction).map(store.dispatch);
backgroundGeoLocation.configure(::geoLocation$.onNext);
```